yfinance printing last three years of a balance sheet
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[221], line 1
----> 1 aapl.get_balance_sheet(start_date="2021-09-30", end_date=None)

TypeError: TickerBase.get_balance_sheet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start_date'

I have tried putting a start and end date, but get an error message.

[ask] and [mre]

Read the error message, read the docs.

appl.balance_sheet does not take parameters. You likely want appl.balance_sheet, (with no parentheses) or appl.history(period="5y") as 3 years is not a valid range for the yfinance API
